# How to read and parse XML without schema in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

Is there a way to read an XML document in Python without the schema? In my use case there is a file similar to the following.

```
<people>
    <human>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <height>174</height>
    </human>
    <human>
      <weight>89</weight>
      <height>187</height>
    </human>
</people>
```

I need to extract an array of `weight` from it. It can easily be done with string manipulation but there must be a cleaner way to do that with XML parser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use ElementTree (included in the python standard library) and do the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse("foo.xml")
myArray = [int(x.text) for x in tree.getroot().findall("human/weight")]
```